# Can I add/remove CAD entity through AutoCAD .NET API

Tags: c#, autocad

Have a requirement to add/remove from a CAD drawing using the .NET API an item drawn as an individual CAD entity in the Title Block area which is not an attribute. Is there any way using point references on a CAD drawing or any other method that this could be done through the API?

The CAD entity been asked to remove has an image, client address and web address.

Use this for accessing attributes

```
BlockTableRecord blkTblRecTitle = 
    transaction.GetObject(blockTable[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace], 
       OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;
        foreach (ObjectId id in blkTblRecTitle)
        {
            DBObject obj = transaction.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);
            BlockReference blkRef = obj as BlockReference;
            if (blkRef != null)
            {
                AttributeCollection attCol = blkRef.AttributeCollection;
                foreach (ObjectId objID in attCol)
                {
                    DBObject dbObj = transaction.GetObject(objID, 
                          OpenMode.ForWrite) as DBObject;

                    AttributeReference acAttRef = dbObj as 
                    AttributeReference;
                 }
             }
          }
```

Have managed to find how to add multi line text at a location

```
using (MText acText = new MText())
{
       acText.Location = new Point3d(802, 106.5, 0);
       acText.TextHeight = 2;
       acText.Contents = "Hello World.\nNow need to right align text.";

       blkTblRecTitle.AppendEntity(acText);
       transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acText, true);
}
```

Ideally would like to right align but can't see anywhere how I do this with MText which have to use for multiple lines.

Given problems adding text to Paper Space can't see how ever be able to add an image.

Comment: you'll need a good logic to find the object... once you identify it, then you can remove/delete, but it's hard to suggest how without looking at how the drawing was created (block, entities, etc)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves was added to the drawing by a CAD engineer when asked him replied with "No the image, web address and address are part of the sheet, drawn as individual CAD entities…". As new to using AutoCAD API don't know how to access the entities through the API. Any links would be appreciated as been unable to find anything through searching online.

Answer (score 1):

To edit .DWG files you need AutoCAD engine, which can be:

1. **desktop**: using the existing AutoCAD on your machine, create a .NET/VBA/LISP/C++ plugin that will open, read, modify and save the file. [Here is a .NET tutorial](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=16459234).
2. **cloud**: using Forge Design Automation webservice to run custom commands/routines with your files. Check the [documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/).

Then I would suggest reviewing the blogs [here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/) and [here](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/) for sample codes.

Comment: I can access the attributes within the Block Reference as in a collection, but the entity or entities are not accessible through a collection. Also tried to add an MText object to the block reference but got a wrong database exception

Comment: yes, the attributes are inside the collection, other elements you need to check on the drawing, maybe selection by polygon, depending on how your drawing is organized.

Comment: The above has helped me, however, have another issue relating to images which going to raise new question for